# C# equivalent of C++ std::swap

Tags: c#, c++

I'm new to C# and I was trying to swap 2 floats and curiously I wasn't able to find any function that does that.

AFAIK C# library is pretty advanced and contains lots of useful functionality - is there any function already implemented to help me achieve this?

PS: I know how to implement this - I just don't want to reinvent the wheel and implement already existing library functions.

Comment: Your question is about the C# language not C++.  I recommend eliminating the C++ tag.

Comment: Performing a swap in 3 statements may be more efficient than calling a swap function.